# Calling a ControllerA Action from Another ControllerB Action passing some params for ControllerA Action from ControllerB Action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, controller, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I would like to call a `TestController#actiona` from another `ResultController#actionb` passing the parameters for the `actiona` along with the call in rails.
Does anyone know what the most efficient way to achieve this is?

I have tried just calling the method like the code below but getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Sample Pseudocode:

```
 class TestController  < ApplicationController 
    def actiona
       # @value = do_something_with(params) // we are doing something with params
       # render resource: @value, status: 201
    end
end
```

```
 class ResultController  < ApplicationController 
    def actionb
        # new_params = params + some_other_things // building new params
        # @new_value = TestController.new.actiona(new_params) // we are passing the new_params
        # render resource: @new_value, status: 201
    end
end
```

I expect that a call to the `ResultController#actionb` calls the `TestController#actiona` with the `params` and renders the same `@value` that `TestController#actiona` would have returned if we called it directly.

Comment: A controller action is not meant to be called by the action of another controller. A controller action is meant to handle a single request-response cycle. Consider, perhaps, creating a service that provides the shared functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I am going this route and I made typo there, I was to instantiate the TestController there like below

`TestController.new.actiona(new_params)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actiona` is an instance method. You can't call `actiona` on the class `TestController`.
Furthermore, if it would work, you will execute both call to `render`, from `actiona` and from `actionb` which make no sense. A call to a controller action must call `render` only once.

If you want to execute the `actiona` from the `actionb`, you can trigger a redirection using `redirect_to` with your params.

If you just want to render the view of the `TestController`, from the `actionb`, you can specify the expected view when using `render` method.

If you just want to reuse some code, you can extract that part of the code into a concern.

Comment: Thanks I will go with creating a service and abstracting the functionality shared between both controllers into it. 

I made typo there, I was to instantiate the TestController there like below

`TestController.new.actiona(new_params)`